# Solving a double integral with a complex function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I have been trying to solve this double integral. I thought about converting the area in order to simplify the function inside the integral but I only used it to simplify the area of intagration, not the function itself so I don't know which conversion will help.

$$\int _0^3\int _0^3 (4y + x)\sqrt{x + y + 1}  dxdy$$

Any help  would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Treat $y$ as a constant when you integrate by $x.$  Perhaps this bit of reormating $\int\int (x+y+1)^\frac 32 + (3y-1)(x+y+1)^\frac 12\ dx\ dy$ will get you started.

Comment: First of all you have a misleading title. Secondly, you did not even try without change of variable. In fact I think it is easier to solve _without change of variable_. Integrate $x \sqrt{...}$ (and note the integral of $y \sqrt{...}$ over the square region is the same). You can integrate first wrt $dy$ and then simple substitution for outer integral should work.

Comment: @MathLover First of all, sorry if my translation for English was wrong. Second, who told you I didn't try? I still think the way with change of variables is more simple. You don't have to agree.

Comment: @Sh.S yes you may find change of variable simpler and that's alright but also you have not even seen what some of the solutions without change of variable could be. The question has just one answer. Also you may have tried. When I say you did not try, it only means it is not visible to us. Sorry I could have been more clear. If you have not gone through this link, I would encourage you to do it https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the change of variable $x=\frac13(-X+4Y)$ and $y=\frac13(X-Y)$, then $X=4x+y$ and $Y=x+y$, and your integral becomes$$\iint_R\frac13X\sqrt{Y+1}\,\mathrm dX\,\mathrm dY,\tag1$$where $R$ is the region of $\Bbb R^2$ bounded by the lines $Y=X(\iff y=0)$, $Y=X-9(\iff y=3)$, $Y=\frac X4(\iff x=0)$, and $Y=\frac{X+9}4(\iff x=3)$ (see the picture below); the $\frac13$ in $(1)$ is the absolute value of the Jacobian of$$(X,Y)\mapsto\left(\frac13(-X+4Y),\frac13(X-Y)\right).$$In fact, $R$ is the parallelogram whose vertices are $(0,0)$, $(3,3)$, $(12,3)$, and $(15,6)$. Therefore, $(1)$ is equal to on third of\begin{multline}\int_0^3\int_{X/4}^XX\sqrt{Y+1}\,\mathrm dY\,\mathrm dX+\int_3^{12}\int_{X/4}^{(X+9)/4}X\sqrt{Y+1}\,\mathrm dY\,\mathrm dX+\\+\int_{12}^{15}\int_{X-9}^{(X+9)/4}X\sqrt{Y+1}\,\mathrm dY\,\mathrm dX.\end{multline}In other words, it is equal to$$\frac{196\sqrt7}3-\frac{216}7.$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer!
Can I ask what made you choose this change of variables? 
I mean how did you know that D will remain a simple region after the change.

Comment: It is a *linear* change of variable. They always turn rectangles into parallelograms.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you again.